# Visualforce and slickgrid saving changes

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I needed to create a quick-edit, excel-style page for my users and based on recommendations here and elsewhere, I chose slickgrid.  Now I have a visualforce page with a slickgrid implementation, that allows mass-excel-style editing of opportunity line items and it works beautifully.  Problem is saving those changes back to the database.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it done.  I've read about using a hidden input field and JSON, but I'm really unfamiliar with JSON and the REST API.  Not to mention my grid could contain thousands of rows with only a few edited - I only want to update the rows that have changed.

I'm using dataView and onCellChange to process the updates and grab the updated rows, so I know exactly what to update.

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var item = dataView.getItemById(args.item.id);
    item['Est_Total_Price__c'] = item['Est_Quantity__c']*item['CPM__c']/1000;
    item['ischanged'] = true;
    dataView.updateItem(args.item.id, item);
    updateitems[item.id] = item;
});
```

What is the cleanest way to get my updates back to the database?  Is my updateitems object even a valid approach?  I thought about looping through it and just creating my own strings to pass back via javascript remoting, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your JavaScript, your `updateitems` is an object with fields that use the item id and values that are the items (a JavaScript form of an `OpportunityLineItem`). Using the item id as the key makes sure that multiple changes to the same item only produce one entry in`updateitems`. You can turn that entire object into a JSON string directly in the browser:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(updateitems);
```

and send that back using a [RemoteAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_RemoteAction.htm).

Your remote action Apex method can then turn the JSON string back into a `Map` using [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) and then use [JSON.deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize) to reconstitute the (guaranteed unique) `OpportunityLineItem` objects and then update them:

```
@RemoteAction
global static void processChanges(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
    Type t = Type.forName('OpportunityLineItem');
    OpportunityLineItem[] olis = new OpportunityLineItem[] {};
    for (String id : m.keySet()) {
        String s = JSON.serialize(m.get(id));
        olis.add((OpportunityLineItem) JSON.deserialize(s, t));
    }
    update olis;
}
```

**PS**

In this case, as all the `Map` values are `OpportunityLineItem`this simpler code should work:

```
@RemoteAction
global static void processChanges(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, OpportunityLineItem> m = (Map<String, OpportunityLineItem>)
            JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Map<String, OpportunityLineItem>.class);
    update m.values();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks exactly like the bridge I needed.  I'm still trying to learn about JSON and how to use it with Salesforce, and this gives me the direction.  Really appreciate it!